# PHP sybase_connect not found

Tags: php, sybase

I am trying to connect to Sybase backend using PHP. However, when I run:

```
<?php
if (function_exists(sybase_connect)) {
    echo "Exists";
}
else {
    echo "Does not exist";
}
?>
```

it prints "Does not exist." This is on Unix and Sybase is mounted there. What do I need in order to be able to use sybase_connect()?

Thanks!

Comment: If this is php function then you should pass variable parameter with $ sign

    if (function_exists($sybase_connect)) {

Comment: @Hardik while that's true, I think the OP does want it to exist :)

Comment: Decided to go with Perl instead, works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you pass the function name as a string, if it doesn't exist, possibly sybase support is not installed on your server.  If you're on Linux (Debian or Ubuntu, for exammple), you'll need to install package **php5-sybase** (google it).

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
if (function_exists("sybase_connect")) {
```

See here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

Comment: I've tried without quotes for pg_connect and it says function exists.

Comment: If you've tried it as above and it still says it doesn't exist, then it doesn't exist. We'll have to dive in further to help diagnose.